# Set flags within python

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to run the [TensorFlow Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) within a Jupyter Notebook and not from the terminal. In particular, I would like to start the training by calling `train.py`, which has a `main` function

```py
def main(_):
   pass
```

that gets called when running the file with `python train.py <additional flags>` because of this part in the file:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run()
```

I found out that this invokes the main function to start running after it sets the global variables from the flags passed in the terminal:

```py
flags = tf.app.flags
flags.DEFINE_string('master', '', 'Name of the TensorFlow master to use.')
...
```

Is there a way to set the global variable `flags` without changing the script `train.py` and then calling the main function by importing the file. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any documentation on `tf.app.flags`.

Comment: just run it in terminal, don't give yourself a headache, + it will take less resources in terminal.

Comment: For educational purposes I have to create a notebook that explains and runs the object detection api. Therefore, unfortunately it is necessary for me to do it the hard way. Is it even possible?

Comment: in case of training, most likely no, for training you need to run it from a file. i'm afraid you will have to make a tutorial for python in file or at least shell form.